# ¿Cómo accedo al valor de un elemento específico de un diccionario?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo una tupla que contiene listas como elementos, y cada lista contiene una tupla.

¿Cómo podría acceder al valor individual de cada elemento del diccionario?

La estructura sería algo así:

```
mitupla[
 ({"Francia": "Paris", "Habitantes": 60000000}, true),
 ({"España": "Madrid", "Habitantes": 48000000}, false)
]
```

¿Como podría acceder al valor de Francia, España o al true en Python?

Comment: ¿No faltará un `=` entre `mitupla` y el `[`? Es que si no no entiendo qué estructura es esa. Y aún con el `=` no me encaja con la descripción que haces de ella antes.

Answer (score 1):

para acceder has lo siguiente:

```
for t in mitupla:
    print(t[1]['pais'])
```

una observación, si tu estas creando al tupla la forma correcta seria `{"Francia":"Paris", "Habitantes":60000000}` en vez de eso esto `{"pais": "Francia", "capital": "Paris", "Habitantes":60000000}` asi cada valor tendrá un clave y será mas facil acceder a ellas

Comment: Tampoco es muy práctico el uso del diccionario que sugieres.. para valores fijos hay colecciones más adecuadas.. por ej. las namedtuple

Comment: Hombre, claro pero estoy dando una recomendación en base a lo que tiene en su código

Answer (score -1):

puedes usar esto

```
for i in range(len(mitupla)):
    for j in range(len(mitupla[i])):
        midict1 = mitupla[i-1][j-1]   # Primer diccionario (francia)
        midict2 = mitupla[i][j-1]     # Segundo diccionario (españa)
for key in midict1:
    print(key)
for key in midict2:
    print(key)
```

esto imprime

```
Francia
Habitantes
España
Habitantes
```

Comment: pero por que usas el valor `Francia` en el `print` ?  que no se supone que ese valor tiene que salir en pantalla? por que lo colocaste ahi?

Comment: @shadow allí lo corregí

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta por favor vota por esta respuesta